# How can I get ranking of last 10 data of a table

Tags: mysql

I've a table. The table structure is like this

```
ID, UserId, Exam Id, Score, Timing, Date
1,  1,      2,       4,     3.5,    2013-03-05
2,  2,      2,       3,     2.5,    2013-03-05
3,  3,      3,       5,     1.5,    2013-03-05
4,  4,      2,       4,     3.5,    2013-03-05
5,  2,      4,       1,     4.5,    2013-03-05
6,  3,      2,       2,     5.5,    2013-03-05
7,  1,      1,       0,     2.5,    2013-03-05
8,  5,      3,       3,     1.5,    2013-03-05
9,  2,      2,       2,     3.5,    2013-03-05
10, 1,      2,       5,     5.5,    2013-03-05
11, 4,      1,       4,     4.5,    2013-03-05
12, 2,      2,       2,     2.5,    2013-03-05
```

Now I want to display the last 5 exam results with ranking of that individual exam.

Say user 2 takes the last exam which exam id is 2. So in that case for user 2's position will be displayed for that exam only.

At the same time for Id-11 for user 4 it will display the position of exam 1.

and same for the rest 3 ids too (10,9,8) and I want it all by just 1 query.

The ranking criteria is High Score, Low timing and Low User Id.

Anybody please help me out.

Comment: Order by...limit...Google is your friend

Comment: I know order by. But if you read this question I hope you'll understand this is a kind of critical problem

Comment: Are you saying Exam Id 4 would be left out since it is not one of the "last 5 rows by date" you are talking about?  What would be displayed?  all rankings for Exam Id 1-3?  Together or separate? Maybe a sample of your expected output would help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* you are looking to pull the five most recent exams with a unique `UserId` and then order them by some criteria? If that is the case you can use a subquery to get this. I will leave further sorting up to you, but here is the start of what I think you need and a Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8eecd/8

```
 SELECT * FROM TEST where ID IN
    (SELECT max(id) 
     FROM TEST 
     GROUP BY UserId) 
 ORDER BY id DESC 
 LIMIT 5
```

If you get stuck from here, provide what you expect for output.